# Elements-wise matrix algebra in R arrays

Tags: r, matrix

I have two arrays with dimensions: `arry1[2,2,n]` and `array2[2,2,n]`. That is, n two by two matrices.

I want to produce a third array which is the n-element-wise matrix multiplication (i.e., %*%) of `array1` and `array2`. Producing yet another array with dimensions: `array3[2,2,n]`.

Frustratingly, I cannot figure out how to use `%*%` to pull this off, the following doesn't seem to work

```
array3 <- array1[1:2,1:2,]%*%array2[1:2,1:2,]
```

Moreover, the `apply()` family of functions don't appear to enable my operation. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `R`, the element-wise product of arrays is computed with the `*` operator.  `%*%` is reserved for the usual matrix product.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this will work

```
array(sapply(1:5,function(x) a1[,,x]%*%a2[,,x]),dim = c(2,2,5))
```

**Data**

```
a1=array(outer(outer(1:2,1:2),1:5),dim = c(2,2,5))
a2=array(outer(outer(1:2,1:2),1:5),dim = c(2,2,5))
```

Comment: Yep. That did it. Thanks!